# Need to convert number to currency

Tags: javascript, angular

Currently using below code for conversion of number to currency. The only issue is if I have 1000 it is giving 1000 instead I need 1k.

*Current implementation* `1000 - 1000`

*Need* `1000 - 1k`

Tried in lot many ways to get it done but unable to resolve.

```
var number = 12345678910;

var digits = 2;
var suffix = ["", "K.", "M.", "B."];

var nbDigits = parseInt(Math.log(number)/Math.LN10);
var power = nbDigits - nbDigits%3;

var tmp = number/ Math.pow(10, power);
var suffixIndex = Math.min(3, power/3);

var result = "$" + tmp.toFixed(digits) + " " + suffix[suffixIndex];
```

I got this solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666485/currency-filter-for-large-amount-in-angular)

Comment: Read this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-to-round-numbers-into-a-reader-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9345136/1000000-to-1m-and-1000-to-1k-and-so-on-in-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to round numbers into a reader friendly format? (e.g. $1.1k)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685911/is-there-a-way-to-round-numbers-into-a-reader-friendly-format-e-g-1-1k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simplify calculation of number of digits:

```
// From:
var nbDigits = parseInt(Math.log(number)/Math.LN10);

// To:
var nbDigits1 = Math.log10(number);
```

That'll give you the number of digits, without rounding errors. It does return `$1.00 K.` for `1000`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: why not take [`Math.log10`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10) directly?